# Optimal way to implement a module pattern function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, module-pattern

I'm searching for the best way to implement a module function, regarding memory consumption as well as execution time/steps.

To present my approaches I created three examples.

My suggestions are as follows:

**1. Simple way**

```
function module(newId) {
  //private vars
  var settings = {
    id: newId,
    name: ''
  };
  //module object including large amount of code
  return {
    getId: function() {
      return settings.id;
    },
    getName: function() {
      return settings.name;
    },
    setName: function(newName) {
      //[...] large amount of code [...]
      settings.name = newName;
    }
  };
}
```

**2. Sub functions in module**

```
function module(newId) {
  //private vars
  var settings = {
    id: newId,
    name: ''
  };
  //put large amount of code here too keep it outside returned object
  function getIdFunc() {
    return settings.id;
  }
  function getNameFunc() {
    return settings.name;
  }
  function setNameFunc(newName) {
    //[...] large amount of code [...]
    settings.name = newName;
  }
  //returned module object: looks smaller - does it consume less memory?
  return {
    getId: getIdFunc,
    getName: getNameFunc,
    setName: setNameFunc
  };
}
```

**3. Sub functions outside module**

```
//put large amount of code here too keep it outside module function
var moduleFunc = {
  getId: function(settings) {
    return settings.id;
  },
  getName: function(settings) {
    return settings.name;
  },
  setName: function(settings) {
      //[...] large amount of code [...]
    settings.name = newName;
  }
};

function module(newId) {
  var settings = {
    id: newId,
    name: ''
  };
  //returned module object: should be very small in memory
  // - but what about performance?
  return {
    getId: function() {
      moduleFunc.getId(settings);
    },
    getName: function() {
      moduleFunc.getName(settings);
    },
    setName: function() {
      moduleFunc.setName(settings);
    }
  };
}
```

Assume that a huge amount of modules is created and stored in memory, like this:

```
//will myModules be small in memory?
var myModules = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    myModules.push(module('test'+i));
    //does the call to setName perform well?
    myModules[myModules.length-1].setName('just a test');
}
```

Please tell me which creation pattern in regard of performance to prefer and try to distinguish between memory consumption and execution time/steps while enumerating pro's and con's.

Comment: in all cases shown, identical functions can be recycled by the js engines, so RAM diff won't be dramatic. using a prototype or outside  method will likely construct faster that many owns.

Comment: @dandavis Getting it right? I can assume all three to be equal in case of RAM and 2 & 3 construct faster? What about execution time on `setName()` call? Is there more overhead?

Comment: run it on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) and see.

Comment: using Function.bind( moduleFunc.setName, settings) instead of the anon would probably be faster to execute, maybe faster to init. it would be nice if the methods used _this_  (say instead of settings) to avoid having to pre-setup any connection between the generic methods and your instance data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a performance test to see the results:

http://jsperf.com/module-performance-test

**1.** and **2.** are nearly equal.

**3.** should not be used in case of focus on fast execution.